# SQL: How many rows in a row with a specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with following columns

```
userId  | win   | startTime
1         1       1483113030149
2         1       1483110804384
1         0       1483109032694
1         1       1483105707639
2         0       1483096891200
1         1       1483017584986
1         0       1483000326940
```

Now I want to know what the maximum of consecutive wins is (being 2 for player 1).
How do I need to write my SQL query? Is this even possible or are there alternatives?

In other words what has to be placed instead "maximum amount of wins in a row" in the following query?

```
SELECT
    maximum amount of wins IN a ROW
FROM
    TABLE
WHERE
    userId = 1
AND startTime > 1483000000000
ORDER BY
    startTime DESC
```

Comment: you could `COUNT()` them or use `MAX()` and GROUP BY

Comment: Something like this should work... http://rextester.com/HFA67412 ... although it will ignore ties for first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose a three-step query:

1. To every win find the closest lose
2. Count the wins with the same closest lose
3. Select max count

The query works best when starttime is unique for each userid.

```
SELECT seqs.userid,
       Max(wins) AS `longest series`
FROM   (SELECT iq.userid,
               Min(iq.starttime) starttime,
               iq.endtime,
               Count(*)          wins
        FROM   (SELECT tf.userid,
                       tf.win,
                       tf.starttime,
                       (SELECT Min(tl.starttime)
                        FROM   t tl
                        WHERE  tl.userid = tf.userid
                               AND tl.win = 0
                               AND tl.starttime > tf.starttime) endtime
                FROM   t tf
                WHERE  tf.win = 1) iq
        GROUP  BY iq.userid,
                  iq.endtime) seqs
GROUP  BY seqs.userid
```

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20a9ee/24/0)

As @gwc points out: this query will not return users who never won. You can replace `Count(*)` by `Sum(iq.win)` and remove `WHERE tf.win = 1` to include them as well. See this [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f10dd0/2)

Answer (score 1):

@TheConstructor is on the right track but the query will not report users with ZERO wins. Try adding a single loss for user 3 as follows:

```
(3, 0, 1483000326945)
```

It is not reported in the results.

I would propose the following to determine the maximum number of consecutive wins for all users:

```
select Q1.userid
      ,max( Q1.cwins )
  from ( select S1.userid
               ,sum( S2.win ) as cwins
           from ( select S1S1.*
                        ,ifnull( ( select min( S1S2.starttime )
                                     from wins S1S2
                                    where S1S2.userid = S1S1.userid
                                      and S1S2.starttime >= S1S1.starttime
                                      and S1S2.win = 0
                                 )
                                , 9999999999999 ) as endtime
                    from wins S1S1
                ) S1
           join wins S2
             on S2.userid = S1.userid
            and S2.starttime >= S1.starttime
            and S2.starttime <= S1.endtime
          group by S1.userid, S1.starttime
       ) Q1
 group by Q1.userid;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8dedc/5)

Answer (score 0):

This is most easily done using variables in MySQL:

```
select userid, max(rn), min(starttime), max(starttime)
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@uw = concat(userid, ':', win), @rn + 1,
                        if(@uw := concat(userid, ':', win), 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from t cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @uw = '') params
      order by userid, starttime
     ) t
where win = 1
group by userid;
```

If you want to restrict to a given user and/or time period, then put the `where` clause in the subquery.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20a9ee/34) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Your solution is so interesting that I had to test it ;-). But when I insert a user with 3 consecutive wins it counts 4 (`max(rn)=4`). I created a [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20a9ee/9)

Answer (score -1):

I think it is not possible since the result depends on *ORDER BY* keyword.
Depending on your SQL Database, I would suggest the use of an SQL procedure.